# How can I focus on the end of textarea value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my code:

```js
$('input').on('click', function(){
  $('textarea').focus();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea>this is a test</textarea> <br />
<input type="button" value="focus" />
```

How can I focus on the end of textarea value?

---

As you can see, currently when you click on the button, you will be focused on the textarea, but at the beginning of its value. All I'm trying to do is focusing at the end of that textarea value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **setSelectionRange(start,end)**, the arguments are the starting point and the end point of the selection it is setting. If you set both to the last index of the value string, the cursor will be at the end.

```js
$('input').on('click', function(){
  let l=$("textarea").val().length

  $('textarea').focus()
  $('textarea')[0].setSelectionRange(l,l);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea>this is a test</textarea> <br />
<input type="button" value="focus" />
```

Comment: What does `(l,l)` mean ? How could it mean "end of value" ?

Comment: it is the small version of letter "L", i have set it in the example code with **$("textarea").val().length**, and it is the length of textarea value string. If you set the beginning of the selection to the end of the string, end the end of the selection to the same, it basically selects nothing at the end of the string, which just puts the cursor there with a selection size of zero

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following way:

```js
$('input').on('click', function(){
  var preVal = $('#txtArea').val();
  $('#txtArea').val('');
  $('#txtArea').focus().val(preVal);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="txtArea">this is a test</textarea> <br />
<input type="button" value="focus" />
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to go about it is as follows:

1. Capture the previous text.
2. focus.
3. append `' '` to the previous value.

```js
$('input').on('click', function(){
  var text = $('textarea').val();
  $('textarea').focus();
  $('textarea').val(text + ' ');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea>this is a test</textarea> <br />
<input type="button" value="focus" />
```